# Split() at new line in VBA specifically Macros in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to create a macro that reads contents of the table cells, then splits the data at new line and then sends them to a function element by element.

Data in my `cell(1,1)` is like such:
[image: Table Image]

my script looks like below

```
Sub test()
    Dim x As Variant
    Dim Lst() As String
    Dim tbl As Table
    Dim i As Integer

    Set tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
    x = tbl.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text
    'x = "Left" & vbCrLf & "Center" & vbCrLf & "Right"
    MsgBox x
    Lst = Split(x, vbCrLf) '<-- This works with x = "Left"&vbCrLf&.....
    For i = 0 To UBound(Lst)
        'Send it to Funciton
        MsgBox Lst(i)
    Next i
    MsgBox Lst(0)"<-- used this to check is split occured 
End Sub
```

The script for some reason doesn't split the data of cell by new line. I have also tried passing the data straight to split function to resolve the issue but have had no luck. `split(tbl.Cell(1,1).Range.Text, Chr(10))`

I have written a similar script for excel using macros and it works in Excel with no problem. 
Am I initializing the variable in wrong data type or something?

Comment: is it really a `vbCrLf`? Test also `vbLf`.

Comment: vbLf doesn't work but vbCr works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Posted it as an answer so you can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because the delimiter between these lines is not a `vbCrLf`.

Use `vbLf` or `vbCr` instead.